# Ambiguous func in two protocols

Tags: swift

I think it might be just a rare situation, but how can I deal with the same (ambiguous) function from two different protocol. For example, I have these defines:

```
protocol A {
    func foo()
    func bar() -> Int
}

protocol B {
    func foo()
    func bar() -> String
}
```

Now I have a class conforms A and B. Can I implement different versions of `foo()` for A and B separately. If I can do so, how can I call them?

P.S. I know for `bar()`, I can use something like this to make a call:

```
let anInt = (instance as A).bar()
let aString = (instance as B).bar()
```

Is it possible to do similar thing on `foo()` function?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing for foo() as you did for the bar() method? Seems like that should work, casting to the correct protocol first.

Comment: @mikeyq6 I can not even implement two versions of foo(). A redeclaration of 'foo()' error will be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The point of a protocol is that it requires that an object provide a particular method, but the method is not "tied" to the protocol. That's why you can use extensions to cause existing classes to conform to new protocols using their existing methods.

As a note, this sounds like a mistake in the protocol design. Having two protocols require different semantics for the same method name suggests that the method is incorrectly named.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned in the question, it SHOULD NOT happen, but in fact it COULD happen. If I am using other's libraries, two different lib authors might not know each other and happened to make the same func. Let's make another assumption, if the two versions of protocol come from different modules, is it possible to tell them apart when doing a conform? Uh..I guess..no?

Comment: No. A method is a method. If it really came to all of that, you'd have to create an Adapter object to handle it (i.e. an object that held your object and conformed to the required protocol). You'd hope never to encounter such a situation.